I need to store multiple Skills (which are coming from Skill table dynamically) in Skill column in Employee table
In ASP.NET Core 8 MVC, rest of the form is perfect but having issue in Skill column in Employee table. I want to store multiple skills using checkbox while submitting Employee form.
I get an error while submitting:

SqlException: Invalid object name 'EmployeeSkills'.

ApplicationDbContext:
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    // Model
    public DbSet<Skill> Skill { get; set; }
    public DbSet<State> State { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> City { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmployeeSkill> EmployeeSkills { get; set; }

    // ViewModel
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeViewModel>().HasNoKey();

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSkill>()
             .HasKey(es => new { es.EmployeeId, es.SkillId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSkill>()
             .HasOne(es => es.Employee)
             .WithMany(e => e.EmployeeSkills)
             .HasForeignKey(es => es.EmployeeId);
 
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSkill>()
             .HasOne(es => es.Skill)
             .WithMany(s => s.EmployeeSkills)
             .HasForeignKey(es => es.SkillId);
    }
}

Skill model class:
public class Skill
{
    [Key]
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? SkillName { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public ICollection<EmployeeSkill> EmployeeSkills { get; set; } = new List<EmployeeSkill>();
}

Employee table definition:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] 
(
    [EmployeeId] INT IDENTITY (202401, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]       NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [Email]      NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [Mobile]     NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [StateId]    INT           NULL,
    [CityId]     INT           NULL,
    [Address]    NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Gender]     NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [Skill]      NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Profile]    NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmployeeId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_City] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CityId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[City] ([CityId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_State] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([StateId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[State] ([StateId])
);

Employee model class:
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email")]
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobile is required")]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Mobile should be 10 digits")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Mobile should be 10 digits")]
    public string? Mobile { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is required")]
    public string? Gender { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Skill is required")]
    
    public string? Profile { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    [BindNever]
    public State? State { get; set; }
    [BindNever]
    public City? City { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeSkill> EmployeeSkills { get; set; } = new List<EmployeeSkill>();
}

EmployeeViewModel:
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email")]
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobile is required")]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Mobile should be 10 digits")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Mobile should be 10 digits")]
    public string? Mobile { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
    public int? StateId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is required")]
    public string? Gender { get; set; }
    
    public List<int> SelectedSkillIds { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public string? Profile { get; set; }

    public SelectList? States { get; set; }
    public SelectList? Cities { get; set; }
    public SelectList? Skills { get; set; }
}

EmployeeSkill table definition:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeSkill] 
(
    [EmployeeId] INT NOT NULL,
    [SkillId]    INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeSkill] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmployeeId] ASC, [SkillId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeSkill_Employee] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeSkill_Skill] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([SkillId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Skill] ([SkillId])
);

EmployeeSkill model class:
public class EmployeeSkill
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public Skill Skill { get; set; }
}

EmployeeController:
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;

    public EmployeeController(ApplicationDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        _context = context;
        _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Employee/Create
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var employeeViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel
        {
            States = new SelectList(_context.State.ToList(), "StateId", "StateName"),
            Cities = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<City>(), "CityId", "CityName"),
            Skills = new SelectList(_context.Skill.ToList(), "SkillId", "SkillName")
        };

        return View(employeeViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(EmployeeViewModel employeeViewModel, IFormFile profileFile)
    {
        // If a state is selected, populate the cities for that state
        if (employeeViewModel.StateId.HasValue)
        {
            employeeViewModel.Cities = new SelectList(_context.City
                .Where(c => c.StateId == employeeViewModel.StateId).ToList(), "CityId", "CityName");
        }
        else
        {
            employeeViewModel.Cities = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<City>(), "CityId", "CityName");
        }

        // Re-populate the states dropdown for the view
        employeeViewModel.States = new SelectList(_context.State.ToList(), "StateId", "StateName");

        // Re-populate the skills for the view
        employeeViewModel.Skills = new SelectList(_context.Skill.ToList(), "SkillId", "SkillName");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var existEmployee = await _context.Employee.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Email == employeeViewModel.Email);
            if (existEmployee != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Email already exist");
                employeeViewModel.States = new SelectList(_context.State.ToList(), "StateId", "StateName");
                employeeViewModel.Cities = new SelectList(_context.City.Where(c => c.StateId == employeeViewModel.StateId).ToList(), "CityId", "CityName");
                employeeViewModel.States = new SelectList(_context.Skill.ToList(), "SkillId", "SkillName");
                return View(employeeViewModel);
            }

            // Handle file upload
            if (profileFile != null)
            {
                string uploadDir = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadDir);
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(profileFile.FileName);
                string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadDir, fileName);

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await profileFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }

                employeeViewModel.Profile = fileName; // Store the file name or path
            }

            var employee = new Employee
            {
                Name = employeeViewModel.Name,
                Email = employeeViewModel.Email,
                Mobile = employeeViewModel.Mobile,
                StateId = employeeViewModel.StateId.Value,
                CityId = employeeViewModel.CityId.Value,
                Address = employeeViewModel.Address,
                Gender = employeeViewModel.Gender,
                Profile = employeeViewModel.Profile
            };

            foreach (var skillId in employeeViewModel.SelectedSkillIds)
            {
                employee.EmployeeSkills.Add(new EmployeeSkill { SkillId = skillId });
            }

            _context.Employee.Add(employee);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        // If model is invalid, reload the form with existing states and cities
        employeeViewModel.States = new SelectList(_context.State.ToList(), "StateId", "StateName");
        employeeViewModel.Cities = new SelectList(_context.City.Where(c => c.StateId == employeeViewModel.StateId).ToList(), "CityId", "CityName");
        employeeViewModel.Skills = new SelectList(_context.Skill.ToList(), "SkillId", "SkillName");
        return View(employeeViewModel);
    }
}

Create.cshtml view of EmployeeController:
@model Candidate.ViewModel.EmployeeViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Employee Create";
}

<h3 class="text-center pb-3">EMPLOYEE CREATE</h3>

<form asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" class="form-control" value="@Model.Name"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" class="form-control" value="@Model.Email" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Mobile">Mobile</label>
        <input type="number" id="Mobile" name="Mobile" class="form-control" value="@Model.Mobile" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Mobile" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="StateId">State</label>
        <select id="StateId" name="StateId" class="form-control" asp-for="StateId" asp-items="Model.States" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="">-- Select State --</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="StateId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="CityId">City</label>
        <select id="CityId" name="CityId" class="form-control" asp-for="CityId" asp-items="Model.Cities">
            <option value="">-- Select City --</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="CityId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Address">Address</label>
        <textarea id="Address" name="Address" class="form-control">@Model.Address</textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Gender">Gender</label><br />
        <input type="radio" id="Male" name="Gender" value="Male" />
        <label for="Male">Male</label><br />

        <input type="radio" id="Female" name="Gender" value="Female" />
        <label for="Female">Female</label><br />

        <input type="radio" id="Other" name="Gender" value="Other" />
        <label for="Other">Other</label><br />

        <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Skills:</label>
        @foreach (var skill in Model.Skills)
        {
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="skill_@skill.Value" name="SelectedSkillIds" value="@skill.Value" />
                <label for="skill_@skill.Value">@skill.Text</label>
            </div>
        }
        <span asp-validation-for="SelectedSkillIds" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Profile">Profile Picture</label>
        <input type="file" id="Profile" name="profileFile" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Profile" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</form>

I tried without relationship between Employee and Skill tables, but while submitting it will match and verify the SkillId as want to store multiple Skill it will not work.
I want to store multiple Skill while submitting

You cannot store multiple skills into a single column - if you want to have a proper relationship between employees and their skills, you need an m:n relationship with a join table between the two tables

Then how will I be able to do that, From a functionality perspective, It is an Employee Registration Form and Employee could have multiple skills. What is the proper way to do that using checkbox

From the code you provided, we can see that by default, EF will generate the table EmployeeSkills:

Therefore, EmployeeSkills should be configured in the database instead of EmployeeSkill. The table definition is as follows:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeSkills] (
[EmployeeId] INT NOT NULL,
[SkillId] INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeSkills] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmployeeId] ASC, [SkillId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeSkills_Employee_EmployeeId] FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeSkills_Skill_SkillId] FOREIGN KEY ([SkillId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Skill] ([SkillId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

When I insert related data:


